# how to enable copy from a disabled TextBox in IE with GWT?

Tags: gwt, copy-paste

I'd like to have a disabled `TextBox` that the users cannot edit, but still copy from. I've tried both `setReadOnly(true)` and `setEnabled(false)`, separately. Firefox seems to work as desired; the textbox is disabled but users can still copy the value to the clipboard. IE the disabled textbox has a greyed-out background and you can't copy to the clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `HtmlPanel`, `HTML` widget or something else for just wrapping the text since you are marking it as read only, and just give a style to it in order to it looks like a `TextBox`.